# Cannot update a single entity in Many-to-Many relationship

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, model-view-controller

I am currently making project which should have Many-To-Many relationship between groups and users. I should be able to update an user and add one. I have no troubles with adding an user, it gets saved properly. However, when I try to update user, it gives an error that definitely has something to do with that hibernate tries to save groups information. Here is my code.

**User Entity**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
public class User {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "email")
    private String email;

    @Column(name = "firstname")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "lastname")
    private String surname;

    @Column(name = "age")
    private int age;

    @Column(name = "gender")
    private String gender;

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(
            name = "user_group"
            , joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "email")
            , inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "group_id")
    )
```

**Group entity**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "category")
public class Group {
  @Id
  @Column(name = "group_name")
  private String name;

  @Column(name = "description")
  private String description;

  @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "groupList")
  private List<User> userList = new ArrayList<User>();
```

**Controller save method**

```
@PostMapping("/addUser")
public String addUser(@ModelAttribute("user") User user) {
    service.saveUser(user);
    return "redirect:/allUsers";
}
```

**Service save method**

```
@Override
@Transactional
public void saveUser(User user) {
    userDAO.saveUser(user);
}
```

**DAO save method**

```
@Override
public void saveUser(User user) {
    entityManager.merge(user);
}
```

java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'group1_.description' in 'field list

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that I altered my column names in DB but forgot to update it in Entity class. Got to be careful next time:)